# How do I define this column in my training dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have constructed a dataset with two columns X and Y, and have used fit models of orders 1, 2 and 7 on this data (shown in code below) .

I want to create a plot such that only the regression lines come up and the original data comes up as black scatter points, however when i plot each fit model, it comes up with both the regression line and the original data in the assigned colour. This means the original data scatter points don't come up as black, and the legend is very messy. How do I fix this?

Additionally, I would like to add the predicted values for each fit (orders 1, 2 and 7) as additional columns in my training DataFrame. What is the most efficient way to go about this?

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.linspace(0, 18, num=10)
Y = (0.05*X**2)+4*np.sin(X)+1.15*X+2*np.random.randn()

combi = {'X':X, 'Y':Y}
train = pd.DataFrame(combi)
print(train)

linear = np.polyfit(X, Y, 1)
linear_fn = np.poly1d(linear)
#linear_fn is now a function which takes in X and returns an estimate for Y
quadratic = np.polyfit(X, Y, 2)
quadratic_fn = np.poly1d(quadratic)
#quadratic_fn is now a function which takes in X and returns an estimate for Y
order7 = np.polyfit(X, Y, 7)
order7_fn = np.poly1d(order7)
#order7_fn is now a function which takes in X and returns an estimate for Y
plt.scatter(X,Y, color = 'black', label = 'Original Data')
plt.plot(X, Y, 'yo', X, linear_fn(X), '--k', color='red', label='Linear')
plt.plot(X, Y, 'yo', X, quadratic_fn(X), '--k', color = 'green', label='Quadratic')
plt.plot(X, Y, 'yo', X, order7_fn(X), '--k', color = 'purple', label='Order 7')
plt.title('Training Data - Fits')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are unnecessarily re-plotting the original data 3 times which is why you have repeating legend entries. You can first plot your fit lines **only** and then at the end plot the original data *only once*. This way you get rid of your messy redundant legends and have your black scatter points as desired.

I would suggest to post your second question which is not about `matplotlib` but `pandas` as a separate question.

```
plt.plot(X, linear_fn(X), '--k', color='red', label='Linear')
plt.plot(X, quadratic_fn(X), '--k', color = 'green', label='Quadratic')
plt.plot(X, order7_fn(X), '--k', color = 'purple', label='Order 7')
plt.scatter(X,Y, color = 'black', label = 'Original Data') # This line can also go first
plt.title('Training Data - Fits')
plt.legend()
```

[image]